# Show more and Hide details in an AngularJS modal template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having an AngularJS modal template where I project my response from the scope. The template looks something like this:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
<uib-accordion close-others="true">
    <div uib-accordion-group class="mt-1" ng-repeat="x in data.details" heading="{{data.displayName}}">
        <pre>{{ x|json:4 }}</pre>
    </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

I want to display a table with the most important fields of 'x' first then, give a "showMore" field where on button clicked, we would be displayed complete JSON. The Button here works as a toggle to Show important details(table) or the Complete details(Json Response)
I am following a less Angular way, but using Javascript and HTML. The following this the implementation:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
<uib-accordion close-others="true">
    <div uib-accordion-group class="mt-1" ng-repeat="x in data.details" heading="{{data.displayName}}">
        <span id="dots"> <table>..</table> </span>
        <span id="more"> <pre>{{ x|json:4 }}</pre> </span>
        <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
    </div>
</uib-accordion>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
        var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
        var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        if (dots.style.display === "none") {
            dots.style.display = "inline";
            btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
            moreText.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            dots.style.display = "none";
            btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
            moreText.style.display = "inline";
        }
}
</script>
```

How could I not use Javascript and make my needs match? I want to implement a more Angular way, I am new to Angular please mind my brevity. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options straight from Angular. The core principle is to use a variable from your component and check it as well as update in/from your template.

First solution, template:

```
<div uib-accordion-group class="mt-1" ng-repeat="x in data.details" heading="{{data.displayName}}">
    <span id="dots" [hidden]="! showTable"> <table>..</table> </span>
    <span id="more" [hidden]="showTable"> <pre>{{ x|json:4 }}</pre> </span>
    <button (click)="toggleTableVisibility()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
```

And in the component

```
showTable = true;

function toggleTableVisibility() {
    this.showTable = ! this.showTable;
}
```

Second solution, using ngIf, only the template changes

```
<div uib-accordion-group class="mt-1" ng-repeat="x in data.details" heading="{{data.displayName}}">
    <span id="dots" *ngIf="showTable"> <table>..</table> </span>
    <span id="more" *ngIf="! showTable"> <pre>{{ x|json:4 }}</pre> </span>
    <button (click)="toggleTableVisibility()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
```

I did not test this so there might be typos / parsing errors but that's the gist of it. The difference between the two is that with `[hidden]` the content is hidden with `display: none` whereas with `ngIf` the content is simply removed from the DOM.

**EDIT**: modified my answer to reflect an update to the question adding a toggle button.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps, I will try this one out.
<Meta> Just one another question, how can I know such details of AngularJs? Can you suggest some sources to improve? Thanks again.

Comment: Just one more thing, I want to toggle between Table and complete data by clicking on a button. That was my question. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The concept is the same but instead of hiding the `dots` div you apply that to the table when the complete data is shown, i.e. just move the code to the appropriate divs.

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't get that one..
Are you referring to altering the property of showTable from the button?

Comment: Which of your divs contains the table, and which one contains the complete data?

Comment: span id="dots" has the table while span id="more" has the complete data.
I want to have a toggle button or maybe a hyperlink to toggle between the two..

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I thought that by clicking on the table you would toggle the whole data set but if you want to have **another** element that will serve as the toggle, please add it to your question's code and I will update my answer.

Comment: Edited the question, my bad that I forgot to add bout the toggle button.

Comment: I have edited the answer. If you have any errors, try debugging them first then come back here if you still have issues.

Comment: Not working, Tried both: https://jsfiddle.net/umt4o8kd/4/

Comment: I cannot get your jsfiddle to work, I get the following error: `(index):1282 Uncaught ReferenceError: fathom is not defined`